# github zip direct download without parent folder

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to get Github to give me a .zip download link that doesnt include the repo name as parent directory.
So instead of

```
repo.zip
/Myrepo
/Myrepo/File1
/Myrepo/file2
```

I would like

```
repo.zip
/File1
/file2
```

I want this for a minecraft server recource pack,
which requires a very specific file  structure.

I know about releases, which is too unflexible for me (commiting changes, downloading, rezipping, uploading as zip)
and gitzip doesnt seem to work for this purpose either.
Downgit has a rootDirectory=false option, 
but it still gives me a root directory.

Any suggestions?

note: I cant use svn, I need a direct download link to a .zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom Travis CI script to do whatever you want with your files and automatically add them to your release. Might be a bit overkill and too much work to setup though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to download a custom folder without downloading the parent or full repo.

There is an website [GitZip](https://kinolien.github.io/gitzip/) which will allow you to download folder instead of parent.

So instead of downloading

- /Myrepo
- /Myrepo/File1
- /Myrepo/file2

as zip file you'll get

- /Myrepo/File1
- /Myrepo/file2

You just have to copy the link to the single folder.